# how can I get a period right after a theorem number when using \swapnumbers?

Tags: numbering, theorems, amsthm

I am trying to mimic lecture notes formatted like this:

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01-single-variable-calculus-fall-2005/lecture-notes/lecture_25.pdf

I would like to format a theorem style which produces the same result as the line

> 1. Inverse hyperbolic functions.

in the above pdf.  So far I've been trying to keep it simple with the amsthm package, as I'm having a hard time finding a way to do this with ntheorem or thmtools.

My first attempt was to use `\swapnumbers` with the following theorem definition:

```
\documentclass[reqno,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\swapnumbers
\newtheoremstyle{numberfirst}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{\bfseries}
{.}
{.5em}
%
{\thmnote{#3}}

\theoremstyle{numberfirst}
\newtheorem{varthm}{.}

\begin{document}

\begin{varthm}[The angle between vectors]

Let $\vec{u} = \langle {u_1, u_2} \rangle$ and $\vec{v} = \langle {v_1, v_2}
\rangle$ be two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and consider the triangle formed by
connecting the heads of $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$.  The third side of this triangle is 
$\vec{u} - \vec{v}$.\footnote{We could also use $\vec{v} - \vec{u}$.  Either will 
suffice because we are only interested in its magnitude.} Let $\theta$ be the angle 
between $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$, opposite $\vec{u} - \vec{v}$.  

\end{varthm}

\end{document}
```

The other result comes from commenting out `\swapnumbers`, which is actually closer to what I want, but now the numbering disappears!

Comment: It seems that without `\swapnumbers` the last argument of `\newtheoremstyle` should be: `{#2#1 \thmnote{#3}}`

Comment: Okay, that worked perfectly.  Thank you!  So I am clear on this, the `#2` takes care of the numbering, the `#1` takes care of the theorem name, which I have specified to be just a period after `{varthm}{.}`, and the final period comes from the puncutation after thm head given in the definition itself.

Comment: All arguments are explained in the documentation of `amsthm`.

Answer (score 3):

For me the first flaw in your mwe is the usage of `\newtheorem`. You are using `\newtheorem{varthm}{.}`. However the correct syntax as explained in the documentation is:

```
\newtheorem{name}{Printed output}
```

So your period is wrong. Related I think the correct syntax is

```
\newtheorem{varthm}{Varthm}
```

The command `\swapnumbers` (explained in the documentation) places the theorem number at the beginning of the heading instead of at the end. The command affects only common theorem styles.

The command `\newtheoremstyle` is a suitable way to specify the behaviour of a theorem environment. It has 9 mandatory arguments whereby the last argument specifies the heading. At this point it's important to highlight that the command `\swapnumbers` disables the declaration of the ninth argument of `\newtheoremstyle`. So related to your needs I suggest the following avoiding `\swapnumbers` and playing with the ninth argument:

```
\newtheoremstyle{numberfirst}
 {}%space above
 {}%space below
 {}%body font
 {}%Indent amount
 {\bfseries}%Theorem head font
 {}%Punctuation after theorem head
 {.5em}%Space after theorem head
 {#2.~\thmnote{#3}}%Theorem head spec
\theoremstyle{numberfirst}
\newtheorem{varthm}{Varthm}
```

Comment: The period in "indent amount" is wrong: it should be either empty (meaning zero) or a length. You can leave empty the second mandatory argument to `\newtheorem`, as the string `Varthm` is never used. A period should be added after `#3`: `\thmnote{#3.}`

Comment: I'm sorry I just saw this response.  Thank you both very much!